# How can I correctly pass Content-MD5 headers when putting files on S3 using boto's Key.generate_url method?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto

I have a Python app, using boto, where I give a user a temporary URL to upload files to an S3 bucket.

The user's upload access is limited, and I make use of boot's `Key.generate_url` method to create a temporary URL that accepted `PUT` requests.

I have this working fine, but I'd like to ensure that the user payload is not modified between the time I generated the key, and the time of the actual upload.

Therefore, I'm trying to use S3's `Content-MD5` support to ensure checksums match.

However, when I add `Content-MD5` headers to the code, `PUT` requests fail.

In the code example below, if I remove the Content-MD5 header for each step (geturl and uploadfile), then everything works as expected.

Note I've verified that my checksums are correct: If I upload a file without the `Content-MD5` headers, I then access the MD5 on S3, and it does match my local hash.

Here's how I get a key:

```
# geturl
# s3key is a Key instance
# _file is a dict with some info on a file to be uploaded
s3headers = {
    'Content-Length': _file['length'],
    'Content-MD5': _file['md5']
}
s3url = s3key.generate_url(self.ACCESS_KEY_EXPIRES_IN, 'PUT',
                           headers=s3headers, force_http=True)
_parsed = compat.parse.urlparse(s3url)
_file['upload_url'] = '{0}://{1}{2}'.format(_parsed.scheme, _parsed.netloc, _parsed.path)
_file['upload_params'] = compat.parse.parse_qs(_parsed.query)
```

And here's how I upload a file:

```
# uploadfile
headers = {'Content-Length': _file['length'],
       'Content-MD5': _file['md5'],
       'Content-Type': None,
       'Connection': None,
       'User-Agent': None,
       'Accept-Encoding': None,
       'Accept': None
}
stream = io.open(_file['local'])
response = requests.put(_file['upload_url'], data=stream, headers=headers, params=_file['upload_params'])
```

Comment: Have you turned on debugging in requests to see the actual HTTP request being sent, including headers?  That might be interesting to see.

Comment: Yes, sure have. It is sending exactly what I asked it to: `Content-Length` and `Content-MD5` - the reason I have those other headers set to `None` is to remove headers that S3 doesn't expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that on Python 3, in my setup, the MD-5 hash is a byte string, and everything else is a text string. The solution was to decode the byte string before adding it to headers.

Previously, my checksum (`_file['md5']`) was made like this:

```
checksum = base64.b64encode(hasher.digest())
```

Now, it is:

```
checksum = base64.b64encode(hasher.digest()).decode('utf-8')
```